Problem about fixed points in a complete metric space
Let $(X,d)$ be a non-empty complete metric space and let $ f:X \rightarrow X$ be a function such that for each positive integer $n$ we have
(i) if $ d(x,y)<n+1$ then $d(f(x),f(y))<n$
(ii) if $d(x,y)<\frac1n$ then $d(f(x),f(y))<\frac{1}{n+1}$
Must $f$ have a fixed point?
So I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and was wondering whether anyone could provide a hint. I'm not even sure if this is true or if a counterexample exists, since the standard ones like $f(x)=x+\frac1x$ don't satisy the hypotheses.
So far I can show that given $x_0\in X$ defining $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$, if $k$ is the minimal positive integer such that
$d(x_0,x_1)<k+1$ then $d(x_r,x_{r+1})<k+1-r$ for $r=0,1,...,k$.
So defining $y_n=x_{n+k}$ for $n\geq0$, by (ii) you have
$d(y_n,y_{n+1})<\frac1 n$.
But I can't show these $y_i$ are Cauchy using this so can't construct a limit point that would be fixed by $f$. This leads me to think there's a counterexample but I've been unable to come up with one.
Edit: I've found a previous post on this question.
Contraction-like mapping without fixed point?
However, I believe the metric provided for $\mathbb{N}$ is not complete so doesn't provide the required counterexample.

Iirc this is a Cambridge IIa problem sheet question.

Indeed. Do you have any hints for it?

Observation 1: Replacing the metric by $d'(x,y) = d(x,y) / ( 1 + d(x,y) )$ respects the property of $f$. Thus, we may assume $(X,d)$ is bounded.

Observation 2: Regardless of having a fixed point or not, the existence of such a function has consequences on the topology of $X$. Namely, if $X_0 \subseteq X$ is a subspace with $f(X_0) = X_0$, then $X_0$ is necessarily Polish. This discourages looking for counterexamples in the realm of non-separable spaces. (Quick proof: Assume $d$ is bounded by 1 (Observation 1). Fix $x \in X_0$. Then, $(f^m(x))_{m \geq 1}$ is dense in $X_0$. Indeed, given $y \in X_0$ and $r > 0$, take $m \geq 1$ and $z \in X_0$ with $1/m < r$ and $f^m(z) = y$. Then, $d(f(x),f(z)) < 1/2$, and ... $d(f^m(x),y) < 1/m$.

In general, any limit point of a sequence $(f^n(x))_n$ is a fixed point. Hence, if $f$ has no fixed point,  all its orbits are closed and infinite. So we may assume $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $f(n)=n+1$.

@Florian R: I think observation 1 is false. For any $x,y$, one has $d’(x,y) < 1$, but there doesn’t seem to be any reason why, for any $x,y$, $d’(f(x),f(y))$ should be less than $1/2$? This only happens if $d(f(x),f(y)) < 1$, which has no reason to be true in general… but one does have $d’(x,y) < 1/n \Rightarrow d’(f(x),f(y)) < 1/(n+1)$ for $n \geq 2$, at least.

@Aphelli It’s false that any limit point of the orbit is a fixed point. Unless you mean, a point which is a limit of the sequence. The language is unfortunate

@FShrike: I mean that if, for any increasing sequence $(a_n)_n$ and any $x,y \in X$, $f^{a_n}(x) \rightarrow y$, then $f(y)=y$. That’s because $d(f^{a_n}(x),f(f^{a_n}(x)))=d(f^{a_n}(x),f^{a_n}(f(x))) \rightarrow 0$. What am I doing wrong?

@Aphelli I don't believe $f(n)=n+1$ satisfies the conditions, at least under the standard metric.

@Aphelli assuming the sequential limit holds for all $x$, with the same limit $y$, is quite a bit stronger than what either of us originally said

OP: the point is that the metric is (almost) completely free, it’s not the standard metric.  @FShrike: sorry, I didn’t make myself clear. Let $x,y \in X$ and $(a_n)_n$ be an increasing sequence of integers. My claim is that if $f^{a_n}(x) \rightarrow y$, then $f(y)=y$.

I see. Unfortunately I'm unable to come up with a metric that is both complete in $\mathbb{N}$ and such that $f(n)=n+1$ satisfies the conditions.

@Aphelli In general this would be false. Consider eg a periodic point.

OP: I don’t know one either, and I currently can’t disprove that it exists. @FShirke: in this case, periodic points are fixed. The assumption implies that for any $x,y \in X$, $d(f^n(x),f^n(y)) \rightarrow 0$ (this distance is bounded above when $n$ is large enough by $1/(n-D)$, where $D$ is the integer part of $d(x,y)$).

There’s always a fixed point.
This just requires induction.
First, choose any $x$. Applying $f$ repeatedly $ \lceil d(x,f(x)) \rceil+1 $ times to $x$ gives a $y_0$ such that $d(y_0,f(y_0))<1/2$.
Let $y_n=f^{(n)}(y_0)$. Let’s show by induction that $d(y_0,y_n)<1$ for all $n$. We already have $d(y_0,y_1)<1/2<1$. Now, assume that $d(y_0,y_n)<1$. Then, applying $f$, $d(y_1,y_{n+1})<1/2$, so $d(y_0,y_{n+1})\leq d(y_0,y_1)+d(y_1,y_{n+1})<1/2+1/2=1$ finishing the induction.
Now, applying $f$ repeatedly $m$ times gives that for any positive $n,m$, $d(y_m,y_{n+m})<1/(m+1)<1/m$. Thus, for any $\epsilon>0$ and $a,b>1/\epsilon$, we have that $d(y_a,y_b)<\epsilon$, so $y_n$ is Cauchy and so converges to some point $y$ satisfying $f(y)=y$.

Thanks! I see that you essentially needed a boundedness result on the $y_i$
